# Declare a dependency to Google App Engine with Ivy as a whole

Tags: google-app-engine, ivy

I'm trying to manage dependency of a Google App Engine project. I use the eclipse with Google plugin to generate the initial project. So I got following jars inside the project.

```
/war/WEB-INF/lib/appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.6.1.jar
/war/WEB-INF/lib/appengine-api-labs-1.6.1.jar
/war/WEB-INF/lib/appengine-jsr107cache-1.6.1.jar
/war/WEB-INF/lib/datanucleus-appengine-1.0.10.final.jar
/war/WEB-INF/lib/datanucleus-core-1.1.5.jar
/war/WEB-INF/lib/datanucleus-jpa-1.1.5.jar
/war/WEB-INF/lib/geronimo-jpa_3.0_spec-1.1.1.jar
/war/WEB-INF/lib/geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar
/war/WEB-INF/lib/jdo2-api-2.3-eb.jar
/war/WEB-INF/lib/jsr107cache-1.1.jar
```

Instead of check-in these jar files into my source control, I want to use ivy to retrieve these jars during build time. Obviously, I can declare dependency one by one, like:

```
<dependency name="appengine-api-1.0-sdk" org="com.google.appengine" rev="1.6.1"/>
...
```

But I'm wondering if there is a better way than declaring jars one by one, something like:

```
<dependency   name="appengine" org="com.google.appengine" rev="1.6.1"/>
```

My hope is to declare only one single dependency to GAE as a whole. Above dependency declaration doesn't work. Is there a way to achieve this goal without creating my own repository? It looks complexer to setup a repository, soI'm using the offical maven repository(http://repo1.maven.org/maven2).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hey @James, good question.  What do you need to do to setup Ivy with an app engine project?  I have a bunch of jars, and want to do the same thing.

Comment: I finally upload all jars to my private maven repository and reference echo of them in every Ivy module. This is not elegant but it's the fastest way for me to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Ivy will only download additional jars/artifacts if they are explicitly listed as a dependency .

For

```
<dependency   name="appengine" org="com.google.appengine" rev="1.6.1"/>
```

to work, there would have to exist an artifacted named appengine, that has all of your required artifacts listed as dependencies.
Using maven repo you have to list each required dependency yourself.

If you have an own repository, you could build an artifact that supports your requirements, but you would have to maintain that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not sussed out how to do it in one line but here is my ivy.xml & ivysettings.xml

ivy.xml

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
```

*">

```
<dependency org="com.google.appengine" name="appengine-api-1.0-sdk" rev="${com.google.appengine.version}" transitive="false" conf="build->default" />
<dependency org="com.google.appengine" name="appengine-api-labs" rev="${com.google.appengine.version}" transitive="false" conf="build->default" />
<dependency org="com.google.appengine" name="appengine-jsr107cache" rev="${com.google.appengine.version}" transitive="false" conf="build->default" />

<dependency org="org.datanucleus" name="datanucleus-core" rev="1.1.5" transitive="false" conf="build->default" />
<dependency org="org.datanucleus" name="datanucleus-jpa" rev="1.1.5" transitive="false" conf="build->default" />

<dependency org="com.google.appengine" name="datanucleus-appengine" rev="1.0.10.final" transitive="false" conf="build->default" />

<dependency org="org.apache.geronimo.specs" name="geronimo-jpa_3.0_spec" rev="1.1.1" transitive="false" conf="build->default" />
<dependency org="org.apache.geronimo.specs" name="geronimo-jta_1.1_spec" rev="1.1.1" transitive="false" conf="build->default" />

<dependency org="com.google.gwt" name="gwt-servlet" rev="2.4.0" transitive="false" conf="build->default" />
<dependency org="javax.jdo" name="jdo2-api" rev="2.3-eb" transitive="false" conf="build->default" />
<dependency org="net.sf.jsr107cache" name="jsr107cache" rev="1.1" transitive="false" conf="build->default" />
```

ivysettings.xml

```
<ivysettings>
```

```
<property name="ivy.shared.default.artifact.pattern" value="[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />

<resolvers>
    <chain name="chained" returnFirst="true">
        <ibiblio name="ibiblio" root="http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven/" m2compatible="true"/>
        <ibiblio name="utilisoft-nexus-thirdparty" root="http://ut-svn-01:8081/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/" m2compatible="true"/>
        <ibiblio name="repo1" root="http://repo1.maven.org/maven2" m2compatible="true"/>
        <ibiblio name="jboss-hibernate" root="http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/" m2compatible="true"/>
        <ibiblio name="jboss-hibernate-public" root="http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/" m2compatible="true" />
        <ibiblio name="ja-sig" root="http://developer.jasig.org/repo/content/groups/m2-legacy/" m2compatible="true" />
    </chain>
</resolvers>

<property name="com.google.appengine.version" value="1.6.4"/>
```